# Imagem de background não aparece em div sem conteúdo

Tags: html, css

Estou criando uma div vazia com uma imagem de background. Mas quando vou renderizar o site, a div não aparecer. Acredito eu que o erro acontece por não ter conteúdo na div.

Neste caso como poderia eu proceder?

Comment: Como está o seu css? Se você definir dimensões para a div, o bg deve aparecer.

Comment: estou usando o bootstrap. então cada div ja vem com a class de dimensão do bootstrap

Comment: Isso para a largura, né? Mas acho que você precisa forçar uma altura.

Answer (score 6):

Defina a largura e altura da imagem. No exemplo eu inseri uma imagem de tamanho 500x500, logo então as propriedades `width` e `height` serão equivalentes à `500px`. Provavelmente o que faltou no seu código CSS foi o alinhamento do background no centro utilizando a propriedade `background-position:center;`.

Observe:

```css
.minhaDiv 
{
   background-image: url('https://g.twimg.com/Twitter_logo_blue.png'); /* endereço URL da imagem */
   background-position:center; /* centraliza apenas o background - para não cortar */   
   height: 500px; /* defina a largura da imagem */
   width: 500px; /* defina a altura da imagem */
   background-repeat:no-repeat; /* para não repetir o background */
}
```

```html
<div class="minhaDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Só pra resposta ficar mais completa, ia ser legal um demonstrativo com um [StackSnippet](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2115/201). Testei usando `url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/br/img/apple-touch-icon.png')`, mas corta pedaços da imagem...

Comment: @brasofilo haha, obrigado por informar. Agora está tudo certo!

Comment: Fiz uma edição, confira o histórico para ver razões ;)

Comment: Nas próximas vezes serei mais claro ao apresentar uma solução.

Comment: Massa, ++1, tá  redondo agora.

Comment: sendo assim. tudo funcionou perfeitamente. agradeço a todos. o/

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do head, coloquei a tag style onde está toda o CSS configurando a imagem.
A tag div coloquei uma class="imagem" que está sendo utilizada dentro do style no qual está sendo definido o tamanho e largura ocupando 100% da div(que ocupa toda a tela) bem como utilizando um no-repeat para que a imagem não fique se repetindo na tela.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        *{
            margin: 0px;
            border: 0px;
        }
        .imagem{
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a9/Webysther_20131025132658_-_Terceira_Ponte.jpg/1920px-Webysther_20131025132658_-_Terceira_Ponte.jpg") no-repeat;
        }

    </style>
</head>
    <body>
            <div class="imagem">

            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Resultado: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]